# The way to get full innerHTML in createdCallback while it has script tags

Tags: javascript, custom-element

```
<script>
  var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
  proto.createdCallback = function() {
    this._innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
  }
  document.registerElement('template-mini', {
    prototype: proto
  })
</script>

<template-mini id='example1'>
  <script type='text/beforeUpdate'>
    console.log('hi')
    this.name = 'Bob'
  </script>
  <p>hello {{name}}</p>
</template-mini>

<template-mini id='example2'>
  <p>hello</p>
  <script type='text/beforeUpdate'>
    console.log('hi')
  </script>
</template-mini>

<script>
  console.log(example1._innerHTML)
  console.log(example2._innerHTML)
</script>
```

I'm developing a custom-element called `template-mini` https://github.com/zhoukekestar/webcomponents/tree/master/components/template-mini

When i use this template-mini, i need a preprocessor to modify data or add some function that can be used in template. So i have a script typed `beforeUpdate`, Unfortunately, i had the below issue:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=502872

What should i do ? I want to get full innerHTML ( the script will be executed by my custom element ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions.

**1.** If you can, wait for the document to be loaded before registering the `<template-mini>` custom element. Therefore you'll be sure that the content of the element is fully parsed when `createdCallback()` is called:

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.registerElement( 'template-mini', { prototype: proto } )
} )
```

**2.** Use another tag than `<script>`, for example `<script-mini>`. Anyway because of its specific `type` attribute it won't be interpreted as a normal `script` element.

**3.** You can defer the time you'll get the content by using a function like `setTimeout()` or `requestAnimationFrame()`:

```
proto.createdCallback= function () {
    setTimeout( function ( e ) {
        e._innerHTML = e.innerHTML  
        console.log( e._innerHTML ) 
    }, 0, this )
}
```

I'd recommend solution 2.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It's great. I use the solution 3 now. Solution 2 Maybe better. Emmm.... now i have another issue about the `img` tag in my `template-mini`. It's always request an invalid image before i append it to dom. The code executed on browser console will request the invalid img. `var wrapper = document.createElement('div');wrapper.innerHTML = '<img src="/img/src/{{img.src}}">'` Any ideas? Or i have to use something like this `<script type='text/template-mini'><img src="{{img.src}}"></script>`'

Comment: @周柯柯 can you post another question exposing the issue?

Comment: I google it, and got some solutions: `<img class="lazy" data-src="{{img.src}}">` OR `<img-mini src="{{img.src}}">`. Thanks anyway~ 

Comment: @zhoukekestar  thanks, you can upvote if it helped :-)